# assign choices to select dropdown at display time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

if i've got a form like this

```
class ProductAddToCartForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'2', 'value':'1', 'class':'quantity', 'maxlength':'5'}), error_messages={'invalid':'Please enter a valid quantity.'}, min_value=1)
    size_option = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=()))
    product_slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

why can't i do the following in my view?

```
    form = ProductAddToCartForm(request=request, label_suffix=':')
    if product.has_options():
        Prod_Choices = product.get_options()
        form.fields['size_option'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=Prod_Choices))
    else: 
        form.fields['size_option'].widget.attrs['type'] = "hidden"
```

the obvious use of this is in a minishop where im trying to show a drop down of options which may or may not be present for eachitem. if there is no optinos i want to dhide the dropdown

I've managed to do this a different way, that is i can do it in the template by checking of the optionset exists (which is what product.has_options() does) and then populating the dropdown at that point. but that way i have to deal with adding the selected options into the form as it gets posted to the cart. in short, i want to know if there is a reason why i can't do the above.

the code runs fine, but it doesn't hide the dropdown where there are no options.

Comment: i guess the first observation to make is that its far easier to use a different form depending on whether or not there are options on that particular Product. But i'm still unsure how to assign choices to the form in the view even with this different form.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there, I played around in the shell / html and it looks like all this should work.

It looks like you **can** do what you posted.

You said you're unsure how to assign choices in the view? I tested your code, and it looks like it works? `form.fields[myfield] = forms.NewField()` correctly modifies the next call to form display.

Looks like you can directly edit the forms.fields[myfield].choices attribute too.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x+1) for x in range(3)])

# hmm choices is an interesting attribute
>>> form.fields['myfield'].choices
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]

>>> form.fields['myfield'].choices = [('New', 'Choice') for x in range(3)]
>>> form.as_p()
<output reflecting new choices>
```

---

### As for disabling the field:

Your code for disabling it doesn't work is because `type='hidden'` doesn't apply to `<select>` elements.

I think your options for disabling it are:

1. Hide the field. `form.fields['myfield'].widget.attrs['styles'] = 'display:none;'`
2. Delete the field. `del form.fields['myfield']`
3. Choose not to display it in the template. `{% if product.get_options %}{{ field }}{% endif %}`
4. Oh, I see you can use forms.HiddenInput() down below.

Seems like you were 99% of the way there?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? These answers should work :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a dynamic form as a closure in the view, something like this (completely untested)

```
def my_view(request, ...):
    product = ...
    if product.has_options():
        product_widget = forms.Select(choices=product.get_options())
    else: 
        product_widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    class ProductAddToCartForm(forms.Form):
        quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'2', 'value':'1', 'class':'quantity', 'maxlength':'5'}), error_messages={'invalid':'Please enter a valid quantity.'}, min_value=1)
        size_option = forms.ChoiceField(widget=product_widget)
        product_slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    form = ProductAddToCartForm(request=request, label_suffix=':')
```

There are other ways of doing it, but I think the closure way makes for the neatest code.